# Is it possible to view multiple payments on a registration as separate Contributions?

Tags: civievent, contributions, export

I need to export data regularly for the bookkeeping end of our operations, and when there are participants have have multiple payments on their event registration, their payments show up as follows (in both the Contribution list and in the exported file):

Total Amount = the price of their selection regardless of how much they actually paid

Fees = $0, regardless of if there were fees associated with their transaction

Net Amount = the price of their selection

What I would like is to have the individual transactions associated with their registration show up as individual contributions. As it is, it is very confusing.

Does this need to be a feature request? Is it a bug? Is there a work around for this?

Here are some screenshots of a specific case:

This is the detail of an event registration, with two payments totaling $725.
[image]

This, of course, is the payment details.
[image]

Here is how this shows up in the list of contributions. It may (or may not) make sense from an accounting perspective to list $785 as the total amount put into an Accounts Payable, but I don't want that level of accounting in my civi installation. I just want to be able to see in the contribution list that this person made two payments, on these dates, in these amounts, not that they promised to make this one payment when they first signed up.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide some screen shot of the price list and also are you using price set for the Fee amount ?

Comment: Added some screen shots. I am using a fixed price list.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand what you are trying to do - yes this is the way Civi works

**For Accountant Point of View** 
I guess they will be more interested in the CSV from batch export which will make more sense to them 
[image]

where you can see Credit account type clearly says

INC (Invoice)        - 1000 
AR  (Amount received)- 10 + 990 => 1000

with different nominal codes

If you are not happy with this output then you need to create an extension for each changes - I guess this helps

Comment: Thanks, Ramesh. I'm not sure we'll ever use civi with all its accounting features, but maybe we'll grow into it.

Comment: On thing that has stymied me about using batches is that I don't see how I can add a transaction to a batch and have it applied as a payment to someone's event registration. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: Please refer to creating batch ---- https://civicrm.org/blogs/pogstonesarahgladstone/creating-accounting-batch-export-format-accountedge  also   https://civicrm.org/blogs/pogstonesarahgladstone/creating-accounting-batch-export-format-accountedge